# Java Serialization to file

Tags: java, serialization

I was just wondering when serializing any object in java to a file using the ObjectOutputStream, do all the methods to it also get serialized or only the data gets stored to the file?

Comment: only the fields are serialized

Comment: It only saves the objects state, the non-`transient` fields.

Answer (score 1):

Serialization is a process of taking object state and transforming it into a format for storage on disk, or sending over the network.

Object state is fully represented by the fields.

Comment: @EJP, I removed that line.